# THREE.js bevel edges shader

Tags: three.js, shader

In blender there is a shader node that create bevel edges without alterate original geometry.
I think that it works interpolating normals.
In fact, can this be done with a shader in three.js?

Thanks, shader gurus!

Comment: Check out the example here https://discourse.threejs.org/t/cheap-round-edged-box-vertex-shader/8066/9

Answer (score 0):

No. At least in the official repository there is no generic geometry modifier or displacement shader that does what you are looking for.